# Repeat a sequence of edits in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I have this text:

```
gradient
continuité
direction
```

and I would like this one:

```
\donnee{gradient}
\donnee{continuité}
\donnee{direction}
```

In visual mode, I can prepare the sequence `\donnee{` <kbd>ESC</kbd>
then going on each line below, hit <kbd>.</kbd>

But this only changes my text to `\donnee{gradient`
and I'm searching something like: `\donnee{` -> end of line -> `}` in my repeatable sequence.

but I cannot add the <kbd>$</kbd>, able to put my caret at the end of the line,
because it involves returning to visual mode by <kbd>ESC</kbd> that stops the sequence recording.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

I'd do the `ex`-style `:s/.*/\\donnee{&}` on your visual selection.

You can also create a visual-block of the text with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and use `I` to prepend `\donnee{` and `A` to append `}` (after having reselected the same block with <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> for instance).

Another approach is to record a macro with <kbd>q</kbd>:

```
qaI\donnee{<Esc>A}<Esc>jq
```

Would record a `a` macro that prepends `\donnee{` to the line and appends `}` to it and go down a line. Then enter `@a` to invoke the macro, `@@` to repeat the last macro.

For something that may be repeated with `.`, you can also do:
`ciw` to change the word under the cursor, then type `\donnee{`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>, `}`, <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: This is the right answer.